# Prove that if $a_{2n} \rightarrow g$ and $a_{2n+1} \rightarrow g$ then $a_n \rightarrow g$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The problem is in the question:

Prove that if sequences $a_{2n} \rightarrow g$ and $a_{2n+1} \rightarrow g$ then $a_n \rightarrow g$.

I don't know how to prove that - it seems obvious when we look at the definition that for sufficiently large $n$ (let's say $n>N$) we have $|a_{2n}-g|$ and $|a_{2n+1}-g|$ less than any given $\epsilon$ and these  are all elements of $a_n$ when $n>N$ (even and odd terms). Does this need more formal proof?

Comment: which limit are you interested in? $n \to \infty $ ?

Comment: Well, it's quite rigorous. Maybe the only part that needs to be written more thoroughly and formally is the rule for consctructing $N(\epsilon)$ depending on properties of $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$, but in my opinion you have the right idea of proof. Well, this is just what, for example, @AdamHughes did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For $a_{2n}$ there is an $N'\in\Bbb N$ so that

$$n>N'\implies |a_{2n}-g|<\epsilon.$$

Similarly there is an $N''\in\Bbb N$ so that

$$n>N''\implies |a_{2n+1}-g|<\epsilon.$$

So taking $N=\max\{N',N''\}$ we have that

$$n>2N+1\implies |a_n-g|<\epsilon.$$

**Note:**  the whole point is that $n$ is either even or odd (this is just the usual [division algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) for a quotient and remainder with the quotient being $2$), so that $a_{n}=a_{2k}$ or $a_{n}=a_{2k+1}$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$, so that the last line is just $|a_{2k}-g|$ or $|a_{2k+1}-g|$--I leave it as $a_n$ to emphasize that it doesn't matter which it is, because it can be either.

Comment: I don't understand last progression. How did $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$ became $a_n$ after picking $n>2N+1$?

Comment: @qiubit you have it backwards, I'm not turning $a_{2n}$ or $a_{2n+1}$ into $a_n$, I'm doing exactly the opposite:  I'm using that $n$ is either even or odd to replace $a_n$ with $a_{2k}$ or $a_{2k+1}$. Check out my edit for details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for a given $\varepsilon>0$, you will get an $N_1$ from $(a_{2n})$ and an $N_2$ from $(a_{2n+1})$ and you will need to take their *maximum* or so..